# Как загрузить сервер на хостинг

Tags: python, сервер, хостинг, чат

Есть небольшой чатик клиент-сервер. Исходя из того функционала, что мне нужен, он уже работает, но только в пределах моего компа. Хотел бы сделать так, чтобы он оказался на серваке и работал оттуда. В инете искал то, как это делается и пришёл к выводу что либо я плохо гуглю, либо на хостинги загружают только minecraft серваки(они реально на каждом шагу). Так вот, если у кого-нибудь ссылка на норм хостинг и статью о том, как это все провернуть?

Comment: _"небольшой чатик клиент-сервер"_. Расскажите, пожалуйста, об этом подробнее. В интернете довольно много детальных гайдов о том, как развернуть X, используя Y. На данный момент Ваш вопрос слишком общий, и единственной адекватной рекомендацией будет скачать `Putty` (или любой другой `SSH` клиент) и просто подключиться к серверу.

Answer (score 0):

https://www.pythonanywhere.com

Тут бесплатный тариф есть.

Гайдов куча есть по деплою. Вот например - https://habr.com/ru/post/457348/